# SELECT MAX OF COUNT IN PHPMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with **SQLcode**

I have a table

### id | content | id_user | id_store

```
1 |  abc    |  1      | 10
2 |  xzy    |  1      | 10
3 |  abc    |  1      | 10
4 |  abc    |  1      | 11
5 |  abc    |  1      | 12
```

My problem is how i got the result is the count of max (id_store) which is 2* value >= max(id_store)

This is a example, result will be

### id_store | count(...)

```
10      |   3
because (3*2) > max of count = 3
```

Tks everyone

Comment: `count + group by` ?

Comment: sorry, i have wrong in my question, i want to from mydb calculate the max of count in this table: example is 3 and i will select data to get value which is multi with 2 >= (max of count)... @Hackerman

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand your question. Try to use the next query

```
SELECT id_store,COUNT(*) CountOfStore
FROM `Your Table`
GROUP BY id_store
HAVING 2*COUNT(*) >= (
                        SELECT MAX(CountOfStore) -- max of all CountOfStore
                        FROM
                          (
                            SELECT COUNT(*) CountOfStore -- count of store for each id_store
                            FROM `Your Table`
                            GROUP BY id_store
                          )
                      )
```

Hope I understood you rightly.